# Emoticons on domain names

Tags: dns

I recently came across with a really strange campaign on the Internet (http://www.emoticoke.com/) in which CocaCola is giving away .ws domains that contains emoticons:

[image: The domains I'm talking about]

How is this possible? I know you can register domains with accents or other latin characters, but emoticons?

And most important: how can I visit these kind of websites from my phone or PC if there's no such character on my keyboard?

Comment: I doubt this is the right place to ask that question. Mostly due to people in Japan, emojis happen to have a place in unicode like any other characters, so theoretically they are characters like any other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can map these emoticons to some character sequences or Unicode characters and make an [Internationalized Domain Name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) - these can contain any Unicode characters.

Hints to which characters/sequences these particular emoticons are mapped to and how to open these names can be found in the [Terms and Conditions](http://www.emoticoke.com/#legal) (initially hidden, click the corresponding link in the main text to see; the following quotes are from the Google Translate result):

> 4) <...> To register www..ws must access and complete the information required in the various lines.

Which means, these are single Unicode characters

> 5) service is only available for mobile devices.
>
> 6) The service requires that your mobile has enabled emojis function for it to work.

Which means, you need a function to enter [Emoji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji) (or arbitrary Unicode characters) on your device to enter them. Of course, you can always enter a [Punycode representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode) instead, but that's a total PINA to compose by hand.

Comment: Great answer! Really helpful and easy to understand. I'll check out Punycode representation, it sounds like a great idea.